# PDFBox outofmemory when printing

Tags: java, pdf, printing, pdfbox

I have a problem with a Software to print PDF files directly with the default printer. Sometimes I receive an OutOfMemoryError when the user print a PDF file but I don't know what is the problem.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space 
    at java.awt.image.DataBufferInt.<init>(Unknown Source) 
    at java.awt.image.Raster.createPackedRaster(Unknown Source) 
    at java.awt.image.DirectColorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(Unknown Source) 
    at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.<init>(Unknown Source) 
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDDeviceGray.toRGBImage(PDDeviceGray.java:78) 
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.SampledImageReader.from1Bit(SampledImageReader.java:216) 
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.SampledImageReader.getRGBImage(SampledImageReader.java:142) 
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject.getImage(PDImageXObject.java:340) 
    at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PageDrawer.drawImage(PageDrawer.java:793) 
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.graphics.DrawObject.process(DrawObject.java:62) 
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFStreamEngine.java:815) 
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStreamOperators(PDFStreamEngine.java:472) 
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:446) 
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.showForm(PDFStreamEngine.java:178) 
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.graphics.DrawObject.process(DrawObject.java:70) 
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFStreamEngine.java:815) 
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStreamOperators(PDFStreamEngine.java:472) 
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:446) 
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processPage(PDFStreamEngine.java:149) 
    at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PageDrawer.drawPage(PageDrawer.java:189) 
    at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer.renderPage(PDFRenderer.java:208) 
    at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer.renderPageToGraphics(PDFRenderer.java:169) 
    at org.apache.pdfbox.printing.PDFPrintable.print(PDFPrintable.java:184) 
    at sun.print.RasterPrinterJob.printPage(Unknown Source) 
    at sun.print.RasterPrinterJob.print(Unknown Source)
```

I use this code to load PDF file with PDFBox and printing with Java.

```
try (PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(fileToPrint)) {

    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

    job.setJobName(jobName);
    job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(doc, Orientation.AUTO, false, 300));
    job.setPrintService(printerService);

    ...

    job.print(attributes);

    ...

} catch (IOException e) {
    ...
} catch (PrinterException e) {
    ...
}
```

**Method to print with PDFBox**

```
@Test
   public void currentVersionTest() throws IOException, PrinterException {

      String jobName = testDocumentPdf.getFileName().toString();

      try (PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(testDocumentPdf.toFile(), MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly())) {

         PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

         job.setJobName(jobName);
         job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(doc, Orientation.AUTO, false, 0));
         job.setPrintService(printService);

         PrintRequestAttributeSet attributes = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
         attributes.add(Chromaticity.MONOCHROME);

         job.print(attributes);

      }

      checkJobInQueue(jobName);
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

The memory consumption is dependent on several factors such as number of images, DPI settings and so on. You might need to adjust the memory settings for your application.

Please take a look at https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html#outofmemoryerror for some suggestions to improve the memory needs/settings.

Comment: Thank you @Maruan Sahyoun, I will change the code to use `PDDocument.load(file, MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly())` instead of `PDDocument.load(file)`

Comment: After reviewing the problem I found one thing. When I send the Job for printing the PDF file I can see the size on the printer queue and it is too big. For example a document with 268 pages appears with size around 8 GB.

It is very strange, for example if a print the document using Foxit Reader the size is around 57 MB.

The real size for the document is 12 MB and I'm using Windows 7 to check the job size.

Comment: @fjtorres that's very likely because the document is rastered prior to printing by the Java Printing API.

Comment: @fjtorres you could set the dpi parameter to 0 instead of 300. This would mean vector output. However memory usage for java would go up, as printers usually have 600 or 1200 dpi.

Comment: Thank you @TilmanHausherr. I edited the question with new source code for unit test. When I changed the 300 instead of 0 the document size on the printer queue dropped down to 1GB. However when I used the javax.print package the size of the printing in the printer queue is a little more greather than the real size of the file and I don't detect increment of memory or CPU comsumption. I am thinking in change the code to use javax.print package instead of PDFBox and java.awt.print package.

Comment: Unless I missed something, the "new version" does not use PDFBox. This may work on some systems, but not on all.

Comment: Btw your question has kindof evolved. This is not so good, because the answer no longer fits as good as before.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Yes, I am not sure that the problem is associated with PDFBox. I will test the integration between PDFBox and javax.print package.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr After my unit test of the integration between PDFBox and Java Print Service the problem persist and the use the new version of code posted in my question is not valid because generate a new problem with the color configuration. Currently I am using this code `new PDFPageable(doc, Orientation.AUTO, false, 0)` for print with PDFBox.

Comment: @fjtorres then please try the things mentioned in the answer of Maruan.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I added `MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly()` but the problem persist. However I located a PDF with the problem and I extracted the first page that cause this problem to another PDF. Now I have a PDF with single page and every printing fail with this problem. [File with the problem](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0BxY3D0E0fd-8c3ZqSXVWWXQxcm8)

Comment: Could you try the PrintPDF command line. Using that I have no issues with your document. What kind of printer are you printing to? Which OS are you running on? Command line I'm using is `java -jar pdfbox-app-2.0.5.jar PrintPDF SINGLE_PAGE.pdf `

Comment: **OS**: Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bits.
**Printer**: HP printer or CutePDF.

I tested using command line. If I use `java -jar pdfbox-app-2.0.5.jar @MaruanSahyoun PrintPDF SINGLE_PAGE.pdf` the document is printed but if I use `java -jar -Xmx256m pdfbox-app-2.0.5.jar PrintPDF SINGLE_PAGE.pdf` the application thows exception `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`. What is the memory requirement for PDFBox? Is not enought memory to print a PDF with single page?

Comment: @MaruanSahyoun Can you try to execute with `java -jar -Xmx256m pdfbox-app-2.0.5.jar PrintPDF SINGLE_PAGE.pdf` command?

Comment: @fjtorres works fine for me. Tested on OS X, JVM 1.7.0_79

Comment: @MaruanSahyoun I running the same unit test on windows and OS X. The same code fail on windows but works fine on OS X with the same memory settings and the same JVM version (Jdk1.8.0_131). Also I tested the command line in windows with latest version of JDK 1.7 and fail for me.

Comment: could you do a heap dump on OOM and check what's eating up the memory?

Comment: I generated a heap dump using `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` parameter. I´m not expert analyzing this files but 
 Eclipse MAT show possible memory leak in `byte[]` associated with `BufferedImage`. I uploaded the file to [this](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0BxY3D0E0fd-8NXdrcUZXYkdOYUk)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143407/discussion-between-fjtorres-and-maruan-sahyoun).

Comment: Sorry I somehow missed the dialog yesterday. I was able to print from the command line with -Xmx190m on W7 home with 1.8.0_131. When using 1.7 it needed -Xmx300m. Surprise: Oracle sometimes does make existing things better instead of just adding new features. I wonder what your problem is... the very first point in the link in Maruans answer was to increase -Xmx. I use -Xmx2g. It all depends of the files. I won't analyze your dump because I'm not really THAT good with this, and last time I did, all I could find out was that java kept structures that were referenced only by "soft" references.

Comment: Thank you @TilmanHausherr. I will change the -Xmx but I don't understand how a single page generate an OutOfMemoryError. It is very strange behaviour. I created a chat room to avoid unuseful comments on this question.